# Include Http-4.2.1 with Android App

Tags: android, apache, http, version, apache-httpclient-4.x

I wish to include the latest version of Http with my Android App, which is 4.2.1. Now wish to download the library from Apache website and include it in the libs folder and then to the build path of my app.

On including Http - 4.2.1, I got the following output in the logcat

```
08-28 02:42:40.917: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.917: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Decoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/BinaryDecoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/Encoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/BinaryEncoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/EncoderException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/StringDecoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoder;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.927: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/StringEncoderComparator;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:40.937: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HeaderElement;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HeaderElementIterator;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HeaderIterator;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpConnection;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpClientConnection;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpConnectionMetrics;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.847: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpMessage;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequest;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpException;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpInetConnection;': multiple definitions
08-28 02:42:42.857: D/dalvikvm(25641): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpRequestFactory;': multiple definitions
```

**My question** is can I do this? Will this create some conflict with already included version of Http library along with the SDK?

Comment: If you are importing that library and create objects using it explicitly (and are not importing a conflicting library in the same namespace) everything should work well. Why would it not?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think this answers the question.

Comment: Ill make an answer out of it then!

Comment: If you are importing that library and create objects using it explicitly (and are not importing a conflicting library in the same namespace) everything should work well.

Comment: Android SDK has Http build into it, how would I know the class I am importing is from added jar or from SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem does not have an elegant and clean solution. The only option you have is to move all HttpClient classes to a custom namespace ('org.apache.http' -> 'my.http') using maven shade plugin or using a prepackaged fork of the library available [here](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)

**EDIT**

As of today one can also use the official [port of Apache HttpClient 4.3 to Google Android](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, How unfortunate?

Comment: @coding crow: Just imagine how I feel being that very stupid idiot who advocated the idea of rushing the freeze of unfinished 4.0 APIs in order to help Google with the first release of Android.

Comment: If I am assuming correct you are Oleg Kalnichevski. We all appreciate and are thankful of work at http-4.2.1. My belief is Android should figure out some way of introducing new libraries. You work is amazing, keep it going, we will figure out a way.

Comment: @coding crow: lots of people enjoy bitching about HttpClient APIs these days not actually knowing how much of it is the direct result of rushing the API freeze in order to be in time for Android 1.0. I have been gradually rewriting and deprecating a lot of old code. Once 4.3 is released it should be possible to deploy HC 4.3 with minimal changes in parallel to HC 4.0beta1 shipped with Android without running into classloader conflicts.

Comment: That is great. HttpClient is a very important API and web is full of community support for it. Let people bitch, I am using it and lot of great apps out there are using it. I know Instagram is using it. Here is very good library for Android HttpClient http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. So great work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK">
<accessrules>
<accessrule kind="nonaccessible" pattern="org/apache/http/**"/>
</accessrules>
</classpathentry>
```

i fix it modify application's .classpath file like this
and i was find the solution in open source project open-gpstracker